# error C2039: 'serialize' : is not a member of vector type

Tags: c++, boost, vector

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/thread.hpp> 
#include<vector>
#include<boost/asio.hpp> 
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp> 
#include <sstream> 

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

std::string make_daytime_string()
{
    using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
    time_t now = time(0);
    return ctime(&now);
}

class maintain_overlay{

public:
    maintain_overlay():thread_(boost::bind(&maintain_overlay::member_list_server, this))    
    {
        thread_.join();
    }
    void member_list_server(){
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13));

        for (;;)
        {
            tcp::socket socket(io_service);
            acceptor.accept(socket);

            member_list.push_back(socket.remote_endpoint());

            std::string message = make_daytime_string();

            std::stringstream ss; 
            boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss); 
            oa<<member_list;/////////////error comes because of this code

            boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
            boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message),
                boost::asio::transfer_all(), ignored_error);


        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<tcp::endpoint> member_list;
    boost::thread thread_;
    friend class boost::serialization::access;  
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & member_list;
    }



};
```

I get the Error

```
error C2039: 'serialize' : is not a member of 'boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<InternetProtocol>'
```

----edit------

I think a mistake I am making is that i am trying to seriliase the member data instead of a whole object instance...How and where should I declare the seriliase method if I want to seriliase the meber_list vector?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to serialize a `vector<tcp::endpoint>` but `tcp::endpoint` is not serializable.

If you want to send only the IP address and port of the connection, then you would have to extract them from the `tcp::endpoint` or write your own serialization/deserialization method.

You can overload boost's serialization function in a non-intrusive way like this :

```
namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

template<class Archive, class Protocol>
void save(Archive & ar, asio::ip::basic_endpoint<Protocol> & e, unsigned int version)
{
    string ip = e.address().to_string();
    short port = e.port();
    ar & ip;
    ar & port;
}
template<class Archive, class Protocol>
void load(Archive & ar, asio::ip::basic_endpoint<Protocol> & e, unsigned int version)
{
    string ip;
    short port;
    ar & ip;
    ar & port;
    e = asio::ip::basic_endpoint<Protocol>(ip, port);

}

template<class Archive, class Protocol>
inline void serialize(Archive & ar, asio::ip::basic_endpoint<Protocol> & e, const unsigned int file_version) {
    split_free(ar, e, file_version); 
}

}
}
```